# Can we make a square from a rectangular sheet of paper by folding it into halves or thirds breadth-wise and length-wise?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let we have a rectangle shaped paper sheet. Suppose we have 4 rules that we can apply on that paper. The rules are:

1. We can fold the paper breadth wise 3 times.(  i.e if the length of the paper is $l$ then after folding it turns to $\frac l3$).
2. We can fold the paper breadth wise 2 times.
3. We can fold the paper length wise 3 times.
4. We can fold the paper length wise 2 times.

Here folding the paper in breadth wise meaning we are fixing the breadth of the paper and reducing the length. e.g if the length is $6$ cm and breadth is $4$ cm then after applying rule 1 we will get the breadth $4$ cm and length $2$ cm. Here new length $<$ new breadth but we keep new length as our length and new breadth as breadth of the changed paper.

Q. Is it possible to make a square from the rectangular shaped paper by applying those rules in a suitable sequential way?

Here I was Trying to do this problem by considering that the ratio of length and breadth is $r$. Then by using rules we will get the new ratio to $\frac r3$, $\frac r2$, $3r$, $2r$ respectively using 1. 2. 3. 4. So after some steps or maintain the rules in any manner we will get the new ratio of the form $2^m3^nr$ Where $m, n \in \mathbf z$. If we achieve a square then we have $2^m3^nr=1$. Then we get $ m log2 + n log3 + log r=0$. We know that Any subgroup of $\left(\mathbf R, + \right)$ is either cyclic or dense. Is it possible to use that in here. If so how?

Comment: Also, there is the question of where you are starting and what you know about the subject, and what you have done... as well as the source of the problem.  I.e. the first bullet point [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: One example where it is not possible is $r=5$ -- with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we can show that there are no $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $2^m\cdot 3^n\cdot 5=1$.

Comment: @rschwieb: I don't think that really matters, because in any halfway reasonable interpretation, the net effect of all the rules together is that we have a free choice of dividing one dimension or the other by 2 (or 3).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, right. When I initially read it, I thought they were supposed to be asymmetric and that "times" referred to how many operations could be performed. The edits since then reveal it is just halving or thirding. I still don't understand why it's necessary to parrot both rules for both directions, but whatever, things appear to be clear now.

Comment: @rschwieb here it's not necessary to parrot both rules as we are using 4 rules we may never use any one or two or three of the given four rules. My question is it ever possible to go to  produce $r=1$ maybe using limit. If so then what is the logic on it .

Comment: @BhaskarPalit I would have interpreted it to mean "finitely many steps" but then it seems clear that it's not possible. So it seems you do need to allow infinitely many folds, I guess.

Comment: @rschweib yes u r absolutely right. It’s clear that it’s may not always possible to achieve 1 in finite steps. We do need to consider the infinitely many folds.

Comment: If you allow infinitely many folds, something explicitly excluded by the wording of your question, then the answer is of course yes, since $\log 3$ is not in $\Bbb{Z}\log 2$ for the simple reason that $3\ne 2^n$ for any integer $n$. Thus as you suggested, the set $m\log 2 + n\log 3 +\log r$ is dense, so it contains a sequence approaching 0.

Comment: Also while the tags on the question may reflect your actual question, the body of your question doesn't suggest your actual question at all, so the tags appear wildly incongruous. You might want to edit your question body so that it reflects your real question rather than relying on people reading the comments.